# How to add/create a Dev Express report in vs2019?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

How would I add a `Dev Express` (XtraReports) report to a project in `vs2019`?
I am able to upgrade, view and edit existing Dev Express reports using vs2019 but I am failing to create a new report. 
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what kind of "fail" does happened?

Comment: @k0st1x Hi thanks, I am not seeing any option or menu to add a new report.

Comment: what installation do you installed that you've expected reporting menu?

Comment: I have v15.2 and v18.2. In Vs2015, if I want to create a new report I select my project add new item then select report or search for devexpress report. I am failing to do the same in v2019.

Comment: VS 2019 integration requires a  minimum version of DevExpress v18.2.7; please make sure you have that version installed. If so, you can try running the installer in repair mode (run the installer as administrator) to restore the project & item templates.

Comment: @Gnyasha do you installed vs2019 after the dx18.2 installation?

Comment: @k0st1x i first installed vs2019 then dx18.2 afterwards. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DXPerience supported VS2019 starting with 18.2.7
[DX Prerequisites](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/prerequisites)